# How to load data in viewDidLoad of DataViewController, without slowing down pageViewController scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I have a dataViewController, which needs data from an API in order to populate a graph, and some news. The news API call is very fast and easy, but the graph call completely slows down the page scrolling as it is called in viewDidLoad(). I edited the graph API to download the data and then store it to cache, and instead on viewDidLoad, it checks if there is any data in cache, and then if there is some it uses that, but it is still terrible slow when scrolling pages. How can I fix this? Here is some of my DataViewController code that handles everything to do with the chart:

```
extension DataViewController {

func GetOnlyDateMonthYearFromFullDate(currentDateFormate:NSString , conVertFormate:NSString , convertDate:NSString ) -> NSString
{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = currentDateFormate as String
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'-'HH':'mm':'ssZZZ" as String
    let finalDate = formatter.date(from: convertDate as String)
    formatter.dateFormat = conVertFormate as String
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: finalDate!)

    return dateString as NSString
}

//Charts

@objc func handleLongPress(longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let p = longPressGesture.location(in: self.chartView)

    if longPressGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began && isLineChartExpanded == false {
        mainLabelContainer.fadeOut()
        chartViewExpandedConstraints()
        isLineChartExpanded = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    } else if longPressGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began && isLineChartExpanded == true {
        mainLabelContainer.fadeIn()
        chartViewLandscapeConstraints()
        isLineChartExpanded = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}

func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    var xInt = Int()
    //The Currency Unit taken from the exchange section of the API.

    xInt = Int(entry.x)
    let currencyUnit = CGExchange.shared.exchangeData[0].rates[defaultCurrency]!.unit

    chartPriceLabel.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    chartDateLabel.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    chartPriceLabel.isHidden = false
    chartDateLabel.isHidden = false
    chartPriceLabel.text = "\(currencyUnit)\(round(1000*entry.y)/1000)"

    let date = self.GetOnlyDateMonthYearFromFullDate(currentDateFormate: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", conVertFormate: "MMM d, h:mm a", convertDate: self.days[xInt] as NSString)

    chartDateLabel.text = "\(date as String)"
}

//Graph Buttons and states
enum GraphStat {
    case day, fortnight, month
}

@objc func todayButtonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

        self.prices = []
        self.days = []

        CGCharts.shared.graphSetup = .day
        CGCharts.shared.getData(coin: self.dataObject, defaultCurrency: self.defaultCurrency, arr: true, completion: { (success) in
            self.prepareGraph(arr: true, completion: { (success) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 4.0)
                }
            })
        })

}

@objc func fortnightButtonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

        self.prices = []
        self.days = []
        CGCharts.shared.graphSetup = .week
        CGCharts.shared.getData(coin: self.dataObject, defaultCurrency: self.defaultCurrency, arr: true, completion: { (success) in
            self.prepareGraph(arr: true, completion: { (success) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 4.0)
                }
            })
        })

}

@objc func monthButtonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

        self.prices = []
        self.days = []
        CGCharts.shared.graphSetup = .month
        CGCharts.shared.getData(coin: self.dataObject, defaultCurrency: self.defaultCurrency, arr: true, completion: { (success) in
            self.prepareGraph(arr: true, completion: { (success) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 4.0)
                }
            })

        })

}
func lineChartUpdate(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    if CGCharts.shared.graphSetup == .day {
        graphSetup = .day
    } else if CGCharts.shared.graphSetup == .week {
        graphSetup = .fortnight
    } else if CGCharts.shared.graphSetup == .month {
        graphSetup = .month
    }

    //Graph State buttons switch status for highlighting buttons.
    switch graphSetup {

    case .day:
        todayButton.alpha = 0.5
        fortnightButton.alpha = 1.0
        monthButton.alpha = 1.0
    case .fortnight:
        fortnightButton.alpha = 0.5
        todayButton.alpha = 1.0
        monthButton.alpha = 1.0
    case .month:
        monthButton.alpha = 0.5
        todayButton.alpha = 1.0
        fortnightButton.alpha = 1.0
    }

    //Graph data management
    var lineChartEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()

    for i in 0..<prices.count {

        //Graph marker from extension

        if prices != [] {

            let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
            lineChartEntry.append(value)

            let line1 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry, label: "Price")

            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
            dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")

            let dateObjects = self.days.compactMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0) }
            let dateStrings = dateObjects.compactMap { dateFormatter.string(from: $0) }

            self.chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(block: {(index, _) in
                return dateStrings[Int(index)]
            })

            line1.setColor(.white)
            line1.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
            line1.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
            line1.mode = .cubicBezier
            line1.lineWidth = 2.0
            line1.drawValuesEnabled = true
            line1.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
            line1.drawCirclesEnabled = false

            chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:dateStrings)
            chartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
            chartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
            chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
            //Expanded

            chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
            chartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
            chartView.xAxis.enabled = false

            chartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
            chartView.legend.enabled = false

            chartView.dragEnabled = false
            chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
            chartView.drawMarkers = false
            chartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false

            chartView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            //Graph Data.
            let data = LineChartData()
            data.addDataSet(line1)
            chartView.data = data

        }

    }

}

//Dismiss Keyboard when Tap
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,
                           with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
//GraphData
func prepareGraph(arr: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    if Storage.fileExists("\(dataObject)GraphData", in: Storage.Directory.caches) {
        print("Exists")
        self.priceData = Storage.retrieve("\(dataObject)GraphData", from: Storage.Directory.caches, as: [Price].self)
        self.days = self.priceData.map({ $0.date.description })
        self.prices = self.priceData.map({ $0.price })

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //                self.chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 4.0)
            self.lineChartUpdate(dataPoints: self.days, values: self.prices)
        }

    } else {
    self.prices = []
    self.days = []
print("didn'tExist")
    CGCharts.shared.graphSetup = .day

            print("ChartsCleared")
            CGCharts.shared.getData(coin: self.dataObject, defaultCurrency: self.defaultCurrency, arr: true) { (success) in
                self.updateGraph()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.lineChartUpdate(dataPoints: self.days, values: self.prices)
                }
            }
    }
}
//GraphData In Storage
func updateGraph() {

    self.priceData = Storage.retrieve("\(dataObject)GraphData", from: Storage.Directory.caches, as: [Price].self)

    self.days = self.priceData.map({ $0.date.description })
    self.prices = self.priceData.map({ $0.price })

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //                self.chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 4.0)
            self.lineChartUpdate(dataPoints: self.days, values: self.prices)
        }

}
}
```

Here is the actual API call from the API manager file:

```
import Foundation


struct Root: Codable {
let prices: [Price]
}
struct Price: Codable {
let date: Date
let price: Double
}

class CGCharts {


var priceData = [Price]()

static let shared = CGCharts()

var currency = ""
var days = ""

enum GraphStatus {
    case day, week, month
}


var graphSetup = GraphStatus.day

func getAllCharts(arr: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

}


func getData(coin: String, defaultCurrency: String, arr: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

    switch graphSetup {

    case .day:
        days = "1"
    case .week:
        days = "14"
    case .month:
        days = "30"

    }

    let urlJSON = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/\(coin)/market_chart?vs_currency=\(defaultCurrency)&days=\(days)"

    guard let url = URL(string: urlJSON) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let prices = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data).prices
            print(prices.first!.date.description(with:.current))  // "Saturday, September 1, 2018 at 6:25:38 PM Brasilia Standard Time\n"
            print(prices[0].price)
            self.priceData = prices

            Storage.store(self.priceData, to: Storage.Directory.caches, as: "\(coin)GraphData")


            completion(arr)

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()

}

}

extension Price {
public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var unkeyedContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
    let date = try unkeyedContainer.decode(UInt64.self).date
    let price = try unkeyedContainer.decode(Double.self)
    self.init(date: date, price: price)
}
public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
    try container.encode(date.unixEpochTime)
    try container.encode(price)
}
}

extension UInt64 {
var date: Date {
    return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(self)/1000)
}
}
extension Date {
var unixEpochTime: UInt64 {
    return UInt64(timeIntervalSince1970*1000)
}
}
```

Something in one of these two files is just too slow, making page scrolling really annoying. It's only about 2 seconds, but it freezes the paging animation for that 2 seconds, I need to find a way to make scrolling smooth and responsive, even if it means not showing any chart data for a couple of seconds until it loads. How can I do this, and what is it exactly that is slowing everything down so much? I also have a suspition it could be to do with:

```
self.priceData = Storage.retrieve("\(dataObject)GraphData", from: Storage.Directory.caches, as: [Price].self)
        self.days = self.priceData.map({ $0.date.description })
        self.prices = self.priceData.map({ $0.price })
```

as this is looping through a big struct with the data and then adding them to 2 arrays, maybe that is holding everything up while it occurs? Thank you.

Comment: to start with, why don't you try loading of your data asynchronously either using GCD or background threads and see how you go sopecifically the last code snippet.

Comment: @Deepika I've moved all heavy stuff to viewDidAppear, so atleast I can scroll somewhat better, but its still not great. Seems the actual api call is on a background thread, how can I make the last snippet run on the background?

Comment: I have added an answer below. See if this helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
  guard let self = self else {
    return
  }
  self.priceData = Storage.retrieve("\(dataObject)GraphData", from:Storage.Directory.caches, as: [Price].self)
  self.days = self.priceData.map({ $0.date.description })
  self.prices = self.priceData.map({ $0.price })
  DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
   // update your UI here based on the data
  }
}
```